# Ways to get href from instagram

Tags: python, api, beautifulsoup, instagram

Are there any ways to get a 'a href' from 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/' except selenium?
With the help of api I can only get a link to the picture with such type: 
https://instagram.fhel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b6c669ed3b5be0dc9c183412d738acac/5CEC3935/t51.2885-15/e35/c119.0.842.842/s240x240/49787501_1587577534678419_6308372780046107029_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net
I don't need this. I wanna get such link 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BuGpLWsFioq/'. I'm trying to use bs4 and 'lxml' parser in order to do this, but get the result with NO 'a href' in html. 
I need to get to know is it possible to scrape this info or not? It's clear that javascript generates some more info. So thus is it a way to scrape this data except selenium-webdriver?

Answer (score 1):

all the info you are looking for are inside the  `<script type=text/javacript>`

You can get it using the following regex:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import json
import re

def _get_json_footer(html):
    s = str(html)
    r = re.compile('"entry_data":(.*?),"gatekeepers"')
    m = r.search(s)
    if m:
        result = m.group(1)
    return json.loads(result)

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/'
page = requests.get(url)
html = soup(page.text, 'html.parser')
json_footer = _get_json_footer(html)

tagpage = json_footer.get('TagPage')
```

You can then navigate inside the `tagpage` dict to get your data

**EDIT:**

To get the posts link you can just navigate inside the `tagpage` dict:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import json
import re

def _get_json_footer(html):
    s = str(html)
    r = re.compile('"entry_data":(.*?),"gatekeepers"')
    m = r.search(s)
    if m:
        result = m.group(1)
    return json.loads(result)

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/'
page = requests.get(url)
html = soup(page.text, 'html.parser')
json_footer = _get_json_footer(html)

tagpage = json_footer.get('TagPage')

links = []
edges = tagpage[0].get('graphql',{}).get('hashtag',{}).get('edge_hashtag_to_media',{}).get('edges',[])
for e in edges:
    links.append("https://www.instagram.com/p/"+e.get('node',{}).get('shortcode','')+'/')

print(links)
```

**OUTPUT:**

`['https://www.instagram.com/p/Bsh4UcdBRvY/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bq8vAMRHtGB/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn_vfeWhcYL/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bm1QRb2ntWL/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bj5pLHAnVuY/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bfn2QWiHKK5/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BfC4ZnTntq0/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BeomaB6Hb8-/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/vYszwjyLdB/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/sQI6Jfpi3f/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/sO9oXPMr6K/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/qzvHuCHUgH/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/WdlKcCBW3w/']`

You can change the key `edge_hashtag_to_media` by `edge_hashtag_to_top_posts` to get the other values

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It returns the list with json without desired url... I need to get such type of link 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BuGpLWsFioq/' instead of this one 'https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/6cdab508fda6d3d4b8391a5f689de85a/5CEBC7D9/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/49302089_762274880807455_172020459930163729_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net'.

Comment: @OlegRadchenko Please see my edit and tell me if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Let me know that is what you are looking after.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
resp=requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/")
html = resp.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')


for a in soup.find_all('link',rel='alternate',href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```

Output :

```
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=en
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=fr
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=it
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=de
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=zh-cn
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=zh-tw
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=ja
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=ko
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=pt
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=pt-br
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=af
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=cs
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=da
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=el
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=fi
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=hr
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=hu
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=id
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=ms
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=nb
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=nl
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=pl
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=ru
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=sk
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=sv
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=th
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=tl
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=tr
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=hi
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=bn
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=gu
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=kn
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=ml
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=mr
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=pa
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=ta
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=te
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=ne
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=si
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=ur
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=vi
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=bg
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=fr-ca
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=ro
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=sr
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=uk
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=zh-hk
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/?hl=es-la
```

Comment: I need to get this type of links "https://www.instagram.com/p/BuGpLWsFioq/" from this url 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/SOMEHASHTAGHERE/'

Comment: Let me know if that helps you.